# Display two divs next to each other but first one is centered

Tags: html, css, wordpress, elementor

I have a problem with something that seems to be simple, but I can't find a solution.
I am using Elementor for WordPress and I would like to have a always centered menu with another div with instagram icon next to it. As far as displaying alone menu in the center of the screen is not a problem at all then putting the mentioned div in same line and keep the menu centered becomes quite problematic. I knot about using `float: left` solution and other that, but then the menu width couldn't be 100% and because of that it won't be centered anymore.
Which approach should I take to achieve my gol?

Comment: Show a minimal reproducible example. Use the <> icon to add HTML/CSS here that readers can see. Otherwise I suspect nobody is going to try to guess what your actual problem is.

Comment: Have you tried positioning the icon absolute, so it doesn’t affect the menu position?

Answer (score 1):

So it seems that both divs needs to have `width` set to `inline (auto)` and column `vertical align` set to `middle`. But then they are really next to each othe and I can't use margin or padding for the instagram icon without moving the menu.